# white powder around battery but not on terminal. Is the battery bad?

Tags: battery

Car cannot start today in California mild weather. I tried to jump start but failed, maybe the jump starter need a bit longer for charging. What's weird is I noticed the white powder around the battery but not around terminals. Previously I noticed that around terminals for other batteries.

Does this mean there is a leak in the battery and I should replace it ASAP?

[image: car battery]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [White Powder Forming on Battery Hold Down Bracket](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/21882/white-powder-forming-on-battery-hold-down-bracket)

Comment: @GdD - No, that does not answer the question of, "... should I replace it ASAP?"

Comment: That battery is 3 1/2 years old so it might be due for replacement. You can disconnect it and bring in to almost any auto parts store or service center and they'll be able to test it. Hopefully you have a friend or family member that can give you a ride because carrying a heavy car battery is not fun regardless of distance :-)

Comment: so I replaced the battery but the car still cannot be started. I called the tow truck and the driver started it without any problem. His trick is to press the gas pedal when trying to start the car. I am still not sure if the battery was bad.

Comment: Use baking soda and water mixture to neutralize the acid before battery removal. There may be some under the battery on the battery tray, neutralize that also.

Answer (score 0):

No it won't hurt the battery life. A quick fix for this is a penny placed beside each post to gather the corrosion.